# Adding another grouping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to mutate a data frame twice, grouping by two sets of columns which intersect each other. i.e.:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% mutate(x = sum(d))
df <- df %>% group_by(a, b, c) %>% mutate(y = sum(e))
```

Is there a faster/more elegant way to do this? I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(a, b) %>%
    mutate(x = sum(d)) %>%
    group_by(c) %>%
    mutate(y = sum(e))
```

Or perhaps save a variable with the first `group_by` applied and then use it twice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We use `add=TRUE` in the second `group_by` to group by 3 variables, adding `c` in the OP's example-

```
 df %>%
   group_by(a, b) %>%
   mutate(x = sum(d)) %>%
   group_by(c, add=TRUE) %>%
   mutate(y = sum(e))
```

According to the documentation for `?group_by`

> By default, when add = FALSE, group_by will override existing groups.
>   To instead add to the existing groups, use add = TRUE

This can be done in one `group_by` call, but only with non-dplyrish functions:

```
 df %>%
   group_by(a, b) %>%
   mutate(x = sum(d), y = ave(e, c, sum))
```

Comment: Expect inconsitency when using `group_by(..., add = TRUE)` with a `data.table`: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1459

Comment: I'm using `length` and `rank` so I don't think the latter option is usable, nice though it is to know.